# Architecture for SEO

Tags: seo, site-structure, architecture

I have a new domain without any authority, and I am organizing the structure of the website. I want to go first for long tail KWs, and after for the big ones.

My question is, if I have a category page `/milan` trying to rank for the KW "milan" (which I know it will not initially), does that have any effect to rank other URLs inside that category? For example `/milan/activities/` (in this URL I will go for the KW "activities in milan")

The other option would be just `/activities-in-milan/` hanging from the root domain without the category `/milan`. The downside here is that when I scale the project, I will have to change the structure.

Answer (score 1):

To a search engine, each url is unique, regardless of its structure. What needs to be different is the content.  The url itself is a tiny factor in ranking.  A descriptive url helps just a tad with ranking, but also helps users.

I would lean towards maintainability.  You could try `milan/activities-in-milan`, but I  haven't tried this myself.

Comment: The thing is that the content of one URL might affect the position of the rest of URLs. I've started two projects with new domains in the past, and just because the home page was thin content, they went directly to the sandbox, and did not rank for several months. Even giving them induced high quality traffic for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Model your architecture in a way that is clear and makes sense. Especially in a way that would scale. In today's age, these are more of IA/UX/UI concerns than SEO. [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) may have answers about best practices in scaling an information architecture.

I would not get caught up over keywords. It will take time to rank, no matter what. Remember that "authority" does not exist outside of SEO tools. Domain Authority was created by MOZ back in the earlier 2000s. Google does not have a signal like it.

Answer (score 0):

As most of the SEO experts and even as per Google, using the structure /milan/activities/ is a better approach, especially for scalability. However, most people follow the same structure and it all depends on your domain type. For example, If my domain is the automobile, then I will choose the car category then I will choose models, and then car names- car/model/name.

Having a category page like /milan helps search engines understand the semantic relevance and hierarchy of your website. Even if initially, you don't rank for the broader term "milan," it can still positively influence the ranking of sub-pages by creating topical relevance.

If you focus on long-tail keywords like "activities in milan" on your sub-page /milan/activities/, this structure will be beneficial. As your domain gains authority over time, it will be easier to target broader terms with the parent /milan category.

Thanks